# preg replace string containing square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this: `[name-123456]`.

I am attempting to replace the match of this string with some predefined strings.  Here is what I have so far:

```
preg_replace('~\['.$string_to_be_replaced.'\]~', $code_to_replace_it_with, $content);
```

Currently this throws an error, I couldn't find out how to remove the square brackets (even though they are part of the string).  How do I make sure those get removed in a regex so that `[name-123456]` gets replaced with `stringofcode`?

EDIT:

```
$string_to_be_replaced = preg_quote($string_to_be_replaced, "~"); 
$content = preg_replace('~\['.$string_to_be_replaced.'\]~', $str_to_replace_with, $content);
```

this simply returns [name-123456] :p

A vardump produces: `string(16) "\[name\-123456\]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is likely that you didn't assign the result back:

```
$content = preg_replace('~...~', $rpl.., $content);
```

Then you should also escape the `$string_to_be_replaced` using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) beforehand. It's necessary for the `-` in your search string anyway.

```
$string_to_be_replaced = preg_quote($string_to_be_replaced, "~");
```

Would also take care of the `[` square `]` brackets, btw.

And if you're not doing any assertions or complex matching, `str_replace()` might be an alternative.

Comment: There could be multiple instances of these bracket replacements.  So what would the final regex look like?  This: $string_to_be_replaced = preg_quote($string_to_be_replaced, "~"); $content = preg_replace('~\['.$string_to_be_replaced.'\]~', $str_to_replace_with, $content);?  Sorry the back slashes got removed..

Comment: Yes, that looks workable. Albeit if you have a list of square bracket searches and associated replacement strings, `preg_replace_callback` might be the better alternative.

Comment: Well, works for me, http://ideone.com/2CTS75, your problem is likely to reside elsewhere.

Comment: Uhm, including the square brackets twice might be an issue.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using str replace for removing the brackets from the [name-123456] before doing the preg replace.  Was hoping for an all in one solution.

Comment: Don't include the square brackets in the regex then?